# Change read/write permissions on a file descriptor

Tags: c, linux, unlink, dup

I'm working on a linux C project and I'm having trouble working with file descriptors.

I have an orphan file descriptor (the file was open()'d then unlink()'d but the fd is still good) that has write-only permission. The original backing file had full permissions (created with S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR | S_IRGRP | S_IROTH), but alas the file was opened with O_WRONLY. Is it possible to duplicate the file descriptor and change the copy to O_RDWR?

psudo-code:

```
//open orphan file
int fd = open(fname, O_WRONLY, ...)
unlink(fname)
//fd is still good, but I can't read from it

//...

//I want to be able to read from orphan file
int fd2 = dup(fd)
//----change fd2 to read/write???----
```

Thanks in advance!
-Andrew

Comment: `fcntl(fd, F_SETFL, fcntl(fd, F_GETFL) | O_RDWR))` *seems* like it would be the thing, except the man page specifically says that won't work.  I guess there's some reason the kernel "needs" this to be impossible?

Comment: so why do you open it in wronly mode if you plan to read it?

Comment: Or just open it again using the correct flags.

Comment: I guess I like to make things difficult for myself. My code doesn't create the orphan file, but reimplementing to wheel is fun, so maybe I'll have to

Comment: I would assume if a file has been unlinked and the only references to it are write-only, the kernel would be perfectly justified in deleting it and replacing it with the equivalent of `/dev/null`, i.e. discarding all further data written and just keeping a dummy file position.

Comment: @aschepler: You need to remove the `O_WRONLY` flag before adding `O_RDWR`. `O_WRONLY|O_RDWR != O_RDWR`.

Comment: @R..: Linux doesn't allow changing fd access mode. The `fcntl` call may not fail, but any attempt to read that fd will return an error, effectively setting `errno` to `EBADF`.

Comment: Odd, how is `freopen` implemented then? Does it just fail? (It's allowed to fail.)

Comment: @R..: under Linux the very same rules apply. It isn't allowed to change access modes, and also doesn't return an error (in this case a NULL stream). Any attempt to read/write will cause `EBADF` too. If you want a reason for not allowing it, imagine changing `stdin` to allow writes, and `stdout` to allow reads - nonsense

Comment: In general, it seems to me that linux allows some nonsense things to happen for the sake of flexibility. If there was such a function (which I'm hoping there is) and you did change access modes of stdin, that wouldn't buy you much. However, if there isn't such a function, it would make it inconvenient in situations like this.

Comment: Yes, on Linux you can do this by opening `/proc/self/fd/n`. See [this stackoverflow answer for source code](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14515466/14558).

Comment: no need @andrewdotn see my answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, there is no POSIX function to change the open mode. You will need to open it in read / write mode. Since you are created a temporary file, though, I strongly recommend that you use [mkstemp](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/mkstemp.html). That function properly opens the file in read/write mode <s>and unlinks it</s>. Most importantly, it avoids a race condition in naming and creating the file, thereby avoiding a vulnerability in the creation of temporary files.

Comment: mkstemp doesn't unlink AFAIK?

Comment: what MK said. I can always add O_EXCL to open() and retry on fail

Answer (score -1):

```
int fd = open(fname, O_WRONLY, ...)
int fd_ro = open(fname, O_RDONLY, ...)
unlink(fname)
{ write to fd }
close (fd);
read or execute(!) fd_ro
```

Comment: add some details please