# Reopen a file descriptor with another access?

Tags: c, linux

Assume the OS is linux.  Suppose I opened a file for write and get a file descriptor `fdw`.  Is it possible to get another file descriptor `fdr`, with read-only access to the file without calling `open` again?  The reason I don't want to call `open` is the underlying file may have been moved or even unlinked in the file system by other processes, so re-use the same file name is not reliable against such actions.  So my question is: is there anyway to open a file descriptor with different access right if given only a file descriptor?  `dup` or `dup2` doesn't change the access right, I think.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Yes! The trick is to access the deleted file via `/proc/self/fd/n`. It’s a linux-only trick, as far as I know.

Run this program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main() {
    FILE* out_file;
    FILE* in_file;
    char* dev_fd_path;
    char buffer[128];

    /* Write “hi!” to test.txt */
    out_file = fopen("test.txt", "w");
    fputs("hi!\n", out_file);
    fflush(out_file);

    /* Delete the file */
    unlink("test.txt");

    /* Verify that the file is gone */
    system("ls test.txt");

    /* Reopen the filehandle in read-mode from /proc */
    asprintf(&dev_fd_path, "/proc/self/fd/%d", fileno(out_file));
    in_file = fopen(dev_fd_path, "r");
    if (!in_file) {
        perror("in_file is NULL");
        exit(1);
    }
    printf("%s", fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), in_file));

    return 0;
}
```

It writes some text to a file, deletes it, but keeps the file descriptor open and and then reopens it via a different route. Files aren’t actually deleted until the last process holding  the last file descriptor closes it, and until then, you can get at the file contents via `/proc`.

---

Thanks to my old boss Anatoly for teaching me this trick when I deleted some important files that were fortunately still being appended to by another process!

Comment: That's cheating since he explicitly said "without calling open again" - though I suppose if you really wanted to do it, that's a constraint that you would relax.  And he probably meant "without calling open with the same path" anyway.

Comment: What's `/dev/proc/fd/n`, is that a typo? It seems to be `/proc/self/fd/%d` according to your code.

Comment: Whoops, you’re right! I’ve fixed it. I was confused because the mac doesn’t have `/proc/self`, but does have `/dev/fd/n`, though this trick doesn’t work there.

Comment: NO NEED!!!

I can just do this:

    char fname[14] = "/tmp/.zXXXXXX";
    int f=mkostemp(fname,  O_WRONLY);
    chmod(fname, S_IRUSR | S_IXUSR);
    int f_ro = open(fname, O_RDONLY);
    unlink( fname );
then write to f, close it and execute f_ro

Comment: @Zibri That's a different problem than what OP is asking about.

Comment: Cool!  This explains why `echo foo > in; bash -c 'echo bar > /dev/fd/0' < in; cat in` works (prints "bar"), despite `python3 -c 'import os; print(os.write(0, b"bar\n"))' < in` failing ("[Errno 9] Bad file descriptor")

Answer (score 6):

No, the [fcntl](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/fcntl.2.html) call will not let you set the read/write bits on an open file descriptor and the only way to get a new file descriptor from an existing one is by using the duplicate functionality.  The calls to [dup/dup2/dup3](http://linux.die.net/man/2/dup2) (and `fcntl`) do not allow you to change the file access mode.

NOTE: this is true for Linux, but not true for other Unixes in general. In HP-UX, for example, [see [(1)](http://h20000.www2.hp.com/bc/docs/support/SupportManual/c02261726/c02261726.pdf) and [(2)](http://h20000.www2.hp.com/bc/docs/support/SupportManual/c02261727/c02261727.pdf)] you are able to change the read/write bits with `fcntl` using F_SETFL on an open file descriptor. Since file descriptors created by `dup` share the same status flags, however, changing the access mode for one will necessarily change it for the other.

Comment: Also noting that `freopen` has a similar functionality for `FILE *` streams, in that whether access modes are changeable depends on the OS implementation.