# How to change the mode of a tempfile after writing to it in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, temporary-files

I am using the tempfile Python module to create a temporary file. I need to write to the file, and then I need to change the mode of the file so it is read-only (chmod 400). Is there a way I can do this using the tempfile module itself? Or should I look into using subprocess to achieve this? E.g `subprocess.run(["chmod", "400", tmp_file.name])`

Here's an example:

```
import tempfile

tmp_file = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile() # by default this tempfile will have write permissions
tmp_file.write(b'Hello world!')

tmp_file.chmod(400) # I need to be able to change the permissions of the tempfile after I've written to it
```

Comment: You can `chmod` the file like you would `chmod` any file, using `os.chmod` method. But question is, why would you want to do this

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Changing file permission in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16249440/changing-file-permission-in-python)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Change open file access mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29595239/change-open-file-access-mode)

Comment: Doh! os.chmod would definitely be best, but was just wondering if there was a way to achieve this that's built into the tempfile module. Looks like there isn't so gonna work with os.chmod(). Thanks all