File created with fmemopen has no contents after writing
I have some files on disk that I want to read in and concatenate. I don't want to create a new temporary file on disk. So I decided to use fmemopen to read/write to memory and access it using FILE APIs (I had already written other code that just dealt with a single file).
Excluding error checking, I have essentially:
#define MODE_APPEND "a"

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {    
  off_t concatenated_file_size = 0;
  for (int i = 1; i < argc; i++) {
    concatenated_file_size += get_file_size(argv[i]);
  }

  char *buf = nullptr;
  FILE *concatenated_file = fmemopen(buf, concatenated_file_size, MODE_APPEND);

  for (int i = 1; i < argc; i++) {
    FILE *file_to_concat = open_file(argv[i]);
    int c;
    while ((c = fgetc(file_to_concat)) != EOF) {
      fputc(c, concatenated_file);
    }
  }
  rewind(concatenated_file);
  int prevchar = fgetc(concatenated_file);
}

get_file_size just uses stat and open_file is just fopen with error checking - both work correctly from my testing.
However, prevchar is always EOF - somehow nothing is being written to the FILE* returned by fmemopen. Is this how this API is supposed to work? Am I doing something incorrectly?

There's weirdness with fmemopen, I can't remember the details, but what's in my head is that what you actually want for this kind of thing is open_memstream.

I looked at that, but according to https://stackoverflow.com/a/30642781/6185049 we can't use FILE APIs to read from it and have to read from the in-memory buffer instead.

What is MODE_APPEND?  And why are you obfuscating the standard mode strings?

Sorry, I just had constants for them. It's just "a".

You can't read from a write-only (append) file stream.  Using "a" only allows you to append data, not to read from the stream.  Use "a+" or "w+" instead — probably "w+".
If you supplied the buffer (rather than a null pointer), presumably you could access the contents directly by copying from the buffer.  You could use that to see whether the buffer contains what you expect.  With an automatically allocated buffer (you specify a null pointer to fmemopen()), you don't have that option.

... presumably you are allowed to read directly from the buffer. Not with char *buf = nullptr;: "If a null pointer is specified as the buf argument, fmemopen() shall allocate size bytes of memory as if by a call to malloc(). This buffer shall be automatically freed when the stream is closed. Because this feature is only useful when the stream is opened for updating (because there is no way to get a pointer to the buffer) the fmemopen() call may fail if the mode argument does not include a '+'."

@AndrewHenle: I didn't look hard at the code — the "a" vs "a+" problem was my main point.  I've modified that paragraph.  Thanks!

I've never seen fmemopen() used with a NULL pointer like that - I had originally assumed it was an error to pass a NULL pointer and actually went an read the documentation - imagine that.  IME open_memstream() is used when the data is to be accessed after it's written.
